# Hazelcast with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ehcache, hazelcast, jcache

I'm new to Hazelcast and started a project newly with Spring boot, Hazelcast. Now I'm trying to integrate Hazelcast with spring boot. Lot of people have different opinions. But is JCache the best way to integrate Spring boot and Hazelcast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kishore-josyula, Jcache is just one way to integrate Hazelcast with Spring-Boot. Hazelcast is one of the providers that implements Spring Cache abstraction, through both JCache and Spring Cache Annotations. (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#_supported_cache_providers)

Hazelcast IMap & JCache have different features. You can compare & decide:

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#map
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#hazelcast-jcache

I suggest you go with the default `IMap` integration first & see how that works for you, if you don't have any requirements to use Jcache. See some examples:

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/spring-cache-manager
https://github.com/gokhanoner/hazelcast-spring-cache-readtimoeut